# Spock - expand assertions on collection into separate tests like @Unroll

Tags: unit-testing, groovy, spock

In Spock, is there a way I can turn the assertions for each item in a collection into its own test that would pass/fail, similar to what happens with `when` and `@Unroll`?

If I follow the simplest and most obvious approach (documented in [Asserting on a list of items in Spock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13138769/asserting-on-a-list-of-items-in-spock))

```
when: def list = // do a bunch of stuff
then: list.each { ... assert it.foo == bar ... }
```

Then a test failure will stop iteration and not test further items in the list. I could instead build up a list of errors in the loop and then pull the `assert` outside the loop, but I was hoping to get some leverage from the test framework instead.

I could use `where` instead,

```
then: list[idx].foo == bar
where: 
idx || bar 
0   || ...
1   ||  ...
2   ||  ...
....
```

But, this would re-run the whole test multiple times, which isn't what I want either -- I want a single test execution, but with the assertions on each collection element reported as an independent test pass/failure.

Answer (score 2):

How about using a helper method to create your list and then use `@Unroll` as OlgaMaciaszek suggests?

```
class UnrolledSpec extends Specification {

    def bunchOfStuff() {
        println "Doing a bunch of stuff"
        return [-1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    }

    @Unroll
    def "That all numbers are greater than zero [#number]"() {
        expect:
        println "Testing ${number}"
        number > 0
        where:
        number << bunchOfStuff()
    }

}
```

Output:

```
Doing a bunch of stuff
Testing -1

Condition not satisfied:

number > 0
|      |
-1     false

    at UnrolledSpec.That all numbers are greater than zero [#number](UnrolledSpec.groovy:20)

Testing 1
Testing 2
Testing 3
Testing 4
Testing 5
```

Comment: The problem is not getting the list in the first place.  It's the behavior of `where` and `@Unroll` - I don't want to execute the whole test multiple times.  Instead, I want to execute the test once, but split out assertions on individual collection elements to report success/failure independently.

Comment: That's pretty much what happens here. You put your test code inside `bunchOfStuff()` which will be executed _once_ and then you have your assertions in the `where` clause which will be executed and reported individually.

Answer (score 1):

It is also `@Unroll` in Spock.

For further details check the dock: http://spockframework.github.io/spock/javadoc/1.0/spock/lang/Unroll.html

Comment: Yes, my point is that when I use `where` and `@Unroll` it executes the whole test multiple times.  I'm looking for a way to selectively unroll some of the loops within the test.

Comment: I don't think it really executes the test multiple times. I think it only changes the way the report is presented. At least this is how I interpret this statement from the documentation: "Note that unrolling has no effect on how the method gets executed; it is only an alternation in reporting." You can find it here: http://spockframework.github.io/spock/docs/1.0/data_driven_testing.html.

Comment: `@Unroll` and `where` are two different things.  `where` is what causes test to repeat; `@Unroll` changes how the results are presented.

Comment: I don't think this can be done using the mechanism provided by Spock alone. I think the closest you can get is by including whatever code you don't want to repeat in `setupSpec()` clause and then only putting an `expect:` clause with the assertion and the `where` table in the test; this way the test will be iterated over but it will consist mostly of the assertions, so shouldn't give you much overhead.

Answer (score 0):

*it's a single test execution with multiple tests on the same output.*

how about this?

```
when: 
def list = // do a bunch of stuff

then: 
list*.foo == [bar1, bar2, ...]
```

In the end it is just as assertion between two collections. In case you are checking all `foo`s should be exactly same value as `bar`:

```
then:
list*.foo.every { it == bar }
```

Comment: That would still behave as a single test failure - in terms of metrics, it's the same whether one element in the collection fails or all elements fail.